# One-time secret message application using PHP-encryption library

Tags: php, beginner, jquery, security, ajax

By utilizing an existing PHP encryption library ([defuse/php-encryption](https://github.com/defuse/php-encryption)) and a flat file database library ([jamesmoss/flywheel](https://github.com/jamesmoss/flywheel)), my application take a secret message from a user, encrypts it using a key derived from a password, and saves it to a flat file.  The message can then be decrypted by visiting a unique link and providing the same password.  After the message is viewed it is automatically deleted.

**Encryption (encrypt.php):**

```
<?php
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';
require_once 'config.php';

// Configure the data store
$config = new \JamesMoss\Flywheel\Config(REPO_DIR);
$repo = new \JamesMoss\Flywheel\Repository('secrets', $config);

function response($msg, $error){

    $response_array = array(
        'msg' => $msg,
        'error' => $error
    );

    // Return a json object to the requesting page
    header('Content-type: application/json');
    die(json_encode($response_array));

}

// Validation checks
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") {

    $continue = true;

    // Validation: check if it's an ajax request
    if(!isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) AND strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) != 'xmlhttprequest') {
        $continue = false;
        response('<strong>Hold on there...</strong> Submission must be an Ajax POST request.', true);
    } 

    // Validation: check if any of the fields aren't set
    if((!isset($_POST['ot_secret']))
       || (!isset($_POST['ot_encrypt_password']))
       || (!isset($_POST['ot_encrypt_password_confirm']))
       || (!isset($_POST['ot_email']))
      ){
        $continue = false;
        response('<strong>Hold on there...</strong> All fields are required.', true);
    } else {
        $secret = filter_var($_POST['ot_secret'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
        $password = $_POST['ot_encrypt_password'];
        $password_confirm = $_POST['ot_encrypt_password_confirm'];
        $email = filter_var($_POST['ot_email'], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
    }         

    // Validation: check if any of the fields are blank
    if((empty($secret)) || (empty($password)) || (empty($password_confirm)) || (empty($email))){
        $continue = false;
        response('<strong>Hold on there...</strong> All fields are required.', true);
    }                      

    // Validation: check if passwords is long enough
    if(strlen($password) < 8) {
        $continue = false;
        response('<strong>Hold on there...</strong> Your password is not long enough.', true);
    }

    // Validation: check if passwords match
    if($password !== $password_confirm) {
        $continue = false;
        response('<strong>Hold on there...</strong> Your passwords do not match.', true);
    }       

    // Validation: check for proper email format
    if(!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
        $continue = false;
        response('<strong>Hold on there...</strong> Please provide a valid email address.', true);
    }   

}

// If all of the above validation checks pass, continue on
if ((isset($continue)) && ($continue === true)) {

    // Create random encryption key
    $iterations = 10000;
    $salt = mcrypt_create_iv(16, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM);
    $key = hash_pbkdf2("sha256", $password, $salt, $iterations, 16);

    // Encrypt secret message, reference: https://github.com/defuse/php-encryption/blob/master/example.php
    try {
        $ciphertext = Crypto::Encrypt($secret, $key);
    } catch (CryptoTestFailedException $ex) {
        response('<strong>Hold on there...</strong> Cannot safely perform encryption.', true);
    } catch (CannotPerformOperationException $ex) {
        response('<strong>Hold on there...</strong> Cannot safely perform decryption.', true);
    }       

    // Save the data
    $secret = new \JamesMoss\Flywheel\Document(array(
        'salt' => base64_encode($salt),
        'secret' => base64_encode($ciphertext),
        'createdAt' => time()
    ));

    $repo->store($secret);

    // Send email to recipient using SendGrid API
    $sendgrid = new SendGrid(API_KEY_SENDGRID);
    $sendemail    = new SendGrid\Email();

    $message = '<p>A secret message has been sent to you.</p>
                <p>Access it at: ' . URL . '/?id=' . $secret->getId() . '</p>
                <p>Thank you!</p>';

    $sendemail->addTo($email)
        ->setFrom(EMAIL_FROM_ADDRESS)
        ->setSubject(EMAIL_SUBJECT)
        ->setHtml($message);

    //Provide response
    try {
        $sendgrid->send($sendemail);
        response('<strong>Message sent!</strong> Your secret message has been sent to ' . $email . '.', false);
    } catch(\SendGrid\Exception $e) {
        foreach($e->getErrors() as $er) {
            response('<strong>Hold on there...</strong> ' . $er, true);
        }
    }

} else {
    die('Access Denied.');
}
```

**Decryption (decrypt.php):**

```
<?php
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';
require_once 'config.php';

// Configure the data store
$config = new \JamesMoss\Flywheel\Config(REPO_DIR);
$repo = new \JamesMoss\Flywheel\Repository('secrets', $config);

function response($msg, $error){

    $response_array = array(
        'msg' => $msg,
        'error' => $error
    );

    // Return a json object to the requesting page
    header('Content-type: application/json');
    die(json_encode($response_array));

}

// Validation checks
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") {

    $continue = true;

    // Validation: check if it's an ajax request
    if(!isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) AND strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) != 'xmlhttprequest') {
        $continue = false;
        response('<strong>Hold on there...</strong> Submission must be an Ajax POST request.', true);
    } 

    // Validation: check if any of the fields aren't set
    if((!isset($_POST['ot_id'])) || (!isset($_POST['ot_decrypt_password']))){
        $continue = false;
        response('<strong>Hold on there...</strong> All fields are required.', true);
    } else {
        $id = $_POST['ot_id'];
        $password = $_POST['ot_decrypt_password'];
    }          

    // Validation: check if any of the fields are blank
    if((empty($id)) || (empty($password))){
        $continue = false;
        response('<strong>Hold on there...</strong> All fields are required.', true);
    }

    // Validation: check if message ID is too long
    if(strlen($password) > 9) {
        $continue = false;
        response('<strong>Hold on there...</strong> Your message ID is too long.', true);
    }   

    // Validation: check if message exists
    if($repo->findById($_POST["ot_id"]) === false) {
        $continue = false;
        response('<strong>Hold on there...</strong> The message ID you entered cannot be found.', true);
    } else {
        $secret = $repo->findById($id);
    }

}

// If all of the above validation checks pass, continue on
if ((isset($continue)) && ($continue === true)) {

    // Decrypt encyption key using salt and password
    $iterations = 10000;
    $salt = base64_decode($secret->salt);
    $key = hash_pbkdf2("sha256", $password, $salt, $iterations, 16);    

    // Decrypt message using decrypted key, reference: https://github.com/defuse/php-encryption/blob/master/example.php
    try {
        $decrypted = Crypto::Decrypt(base64_decode($secret->secret), $key);
    } catch (InvalidCiphertextException $ex) { // VERY IMPORTANT
        response('<strong>Hold on there...</strong> Something\'s wrong, please double check your password.', true);
    } catch (CryptoTestFailedException $ex) {
        response('<strong>Hold on there...</strong> Cannot safely perform encryption.', true);
    } catch (CannotPerformOperationException $ex) {
        response('<strong>Hold on there...</strong> Cannot safely perform decryption.', true);
    }           

    // Delete message
    $repo->delete($id);

    // Provide response
    response($decrypted, false);

} else {
    die('Access Denied.');
}
```

**AJAX (script.js):**

```
$(function() {

    // Connect to encrypt.php and return response
    $('#form_encrypt').validator().on('submit', function(e) {
        if (!e.isDefaultPrevented()) {
            var formData = $(this).serialize();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                url: "encrypt.php",
                data: formData,
                success: function(data) {
                    if (!data.error) {
                        $("form").trigger("reset");
                        $("#results").removeClass().empty().addClass("alert alert-success fade in").html(data.msg);
                    } else {
                        $("#results").removeClass().empty().addClass("alert alert-danger fade in").html(data.msg);
                    }
                },
                error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                    $("#results").removeClass().empty().addClass("alert alert-danger fade in").html('<strong>Hold on there...</strong> An internal error has occured.');
                }
            });
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    });

    // Connect to decrypt.php and return response
    $('#form_decrypt').validator().on('submit', function(e) {
        if (!e.isDefaultPrevented()) {
            var formData = $(this).serialize();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                url: "decrypt.php",
                data: formData,
                success: function(data) {
                    if (!data.error) {
                        $("form").trigger("reset");
                        $(".nav, .tab-content").remove();
                        $("#results").removeClass().empty().html("<pre>" + data.msg + "</pre>");
                    } else {
                        $("#results").removeClass().empty().addClass("alert alert-danger fade in").html(data.msg);
                    }
                },
                error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                    $("#results").removeClass().empty().addClass("alert alert-danger fade in").html('<strong>Hold on there...</strong> An internal error has occured.');
                }
            });
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    });

});
```

**Front-end (index.php):**

```
<?php
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';
require_once 'config.php';

// Determine if a message is being accessed from link
if(isset($_GET["id"]) && (!empty($_GET["id"]))){
    $fromLink = true;
} else {
    $fromLink = false;
}

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>OneTime</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/styles.css">
        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->
    </head>

    <body>

        <div class="container">

            <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">

                <div class="page-header text-center">
                    <h1>OneTime</h1>
                </div>

                <div id="results"></div>

                <!--LINKS-->
                <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
                    <li role="presentation" class="<?php if(!$fromLink){echo 'active';}?>">
                        <a href="#encrypt" aria-controls="encrypt" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Encrypt</a>
                    </li>
                    <li role="presentation" class="<?php if($fromLink){echo 'active';}?>">
                        <a href="#decrypt" aria-controls="decrypt" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Decrypt</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>

                <!--TABS-->
                <div class="tab-content">

                    <!--ENCRYPT-->
                    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane <?php if(!$fromLink){echo 'active';}?>" id="encrypt">
                        <form id="form_encrypt">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="ot_secret">Your secret message:</label>
                                <textarea class="form-control" id="ot_secret" name="ot_secret" rows="3" required></textarea>
                                <span class="help-block with-errors">Plain text only.</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="ot_encrypt_password">Add a complex password to your message:</label>
                                <div class="form-inline row">
                                    <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
                                        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="ot_encrypt_password" name="ot_encrypt_password" placeholder="Password" required data-minlength="8">
                                        <span class="help-block">Minimum of 8 characters.</span>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
                                        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="ot_encrypt_password_confirm" name="ot_encrypt_password_confirm" placeholder="Confirm Password" required data-match="#ot_encrypt_password">
                                        <span class="help-block with-errors"></span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="ot_email">Who should we send the message link to?</label>
                                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="ot_email" name="ot_email" placeholder="user@example.com" required>
                                <span class="help-block with-errors"></span>
                            </div>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock" aria-hidden="true"></span> Encrypt Secret Message</button>
                        </form>
                    </div>

                    <!--DECRYPT-->
                    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane <?php if($fromLink){echo 'active';}?>" id="decrypt">
                        <form id="form_decrypt">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="ot_id">Message ID</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ot_id" name="ot_id" placeholder="o8AZv0hGh" required  maxlength="9" value="<?php if($fromLink){echo $_GET["id"];}?>">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="ot_decrypt_password">Password</label>
                                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="ot_decrypt_password" name="ot_decrypt_password" placeholder="Password" required>
                            </div>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">Decrypt Secret Message</button>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <hr />

                <!--COPYRIGHT-->
                <p class="small text-center">&copy; <?php echo date('Y'); ?> <a href="index.php">OneTime</a>. All rights reserved.</p>

            </div>

        </div>

        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/js/validator.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/js/script.js"></script>

    </body>

</html>
```

I am hoping to get feedback on all aspects of my project - code style, proper PHP/AJAX use, validation/sanitization of user input, and any other security considerations I should be following.  For the purpose of this project, I'm going to assume that the people maintaining the php-encryption library know way more about encryption than I ever will, so I'm not really looking for feedback on their library.  Similarly, I know a flat file database isn't ideal, but it was the easiest to get up and running - if I were to ever move this to a production server I would likely utilize a more traditional database.

Answer (score 3):

A few things to suggest:

- You should move all your `<strong></strong>` returned messages to a config file, rather than keeping them inline.
- In the following code block, you can return the condition instead of the 
  `if-else` statement:

  > ```
  > if(isset($_GET["id"]) && (!empty($_GET["id"]))){
  >     $fromLink = true;
  > } else {
  >     $fromLink = false;
  > }
  > ```

  into:

  ```
  $fromLink = (isset($_GET["id"]) && (!empty($_GET["id"])));
  ```
- I would avoid having the MAGIC NUMBER \$16\$ in the following line, you should move it to a variable and declare it's purpose, just like `$iterations`:

  > ```
  > hash_pbkdf2("sha256", $password, $salt, $iterations, 16);
  >                                                      ^
  > ```
- In the future, you wouldn't need the `===` (*triple equals*) in the following line, you can just use `==`, but the whole line is wrong anyway. You test if `$continue` `isset`, and then test whether it's `true`. If it was `true`, it would be set. Also, comparing a boolean explicitly to `==`/`=== true` is really bad.

  > ```
  > if ((isset($continue)) && ($continue === true)) {
  > ```

  into:

  ```
  if ($continue){
  ```